# ¿Como hago una busqueda con clases en Java - Netbeans y envio los datos de una tabla?

Tags: java, busqueda

Mi problema es que al momento de hacer una busqueda en java de un formulario a otro quiero que me muestre los datos que encuentro relacionado a la busqueda, pero al hacer la busqueda no me arroja ningun resultado.

Este es mi codigo de busqueda en una clase llamada cliente:

```
public void buscar(String campo, String valor){
        
        try {
            String sql;
            ocon.conectar();
            
            sql = "select * from cliente where '" + campo + "' like '%"+valor+"%'";
            stmt = ocon.con.createStatement();
            rs = stmt.executeQuery(sql);
            while (rs.next()) {
                String[] datos = new String[5];
                datos[0] = rs.getString(1);
                datos[1] = rs.getString(2);
                datos[2] = rs.getString(3);
                datos[3] = rs.getString(4);
                datos[4] = rs.getString(5);
                tdatos.addRow(datos);
            
            }
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Cliente.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
     }
```

con esto invoco a mi metodo:

```
Cliente ocli=new Cliente();
```

y con esto envio los parametros de busqueda los cuales no me arrojan nada

```
String valor = txtbuscar.getText();
ocli.buscar(campo, valor);
```

y campo que son unos radiobutton valen esto:

```
campo = "nom_cli";
```

Comment: Lo mejor que puedes hacer en estos casos es un test de tu código y cuando recién estas iniciando puedes mostrar por pantalla un mensaje cualquiera en diversos bloques de tu código y ver hasta que parte realiza lo que quieres

Comment: se realiza todo menos el resultado de la busqueda establecida

Comment: Terminando el bucle while dentro de tu método buscar, falta la agregar el modelo de  ``table.setModel(modelo); ``; al no tener un código para verificar no se como declaras tu tabla y el modelo de tu tabla.

Comment: Ya puse todo eso y aun asi no me arroja los resultados de busqueda